# List Manipulation and Removing Cases

Tags: list-manipulation, import, data

I've imported a large data set, manually removing headers in the .rtf file where it originates. However, when I import this data, I receive this output:

```
data = Import["//pathtofile//data.rtf"]
Notebook[{Cell["1   3.32    10  10  10  670 600 1
           2    2.26    6   8   5   700 640 1
           3    2.35    8   6   8   640 530 1
           4    2.08    9   10  7   670 600 1
           5    3.38    8   9   8   540 580 1
           6    3.29    10  8   8   760 630 1
           7    3.21    8   8   7   600 400 1
           8    2.00    3   7   6   460 530 1
           9    3.18    9   10  8   670 450 1
          10    2.34    7   7   6   570 480 1
          11    3.08    9   10  6   491 488 1
          12    3.34    5   9   7   600 600 1
          13    1.40    6   8   8   510 530 1
          14    1.43    10  9   9   750 610 1
          15    2.48    8   9   6   650 460 1
          16    3.73    10  10  9   720 630 1
          17    3.80    10  10  9   760 500 1
          18    4.00    9   9   8   800 610 1
          19    2.00    9   6   5   640 670 1
          20    3.74    9   10  9   750 700 1
          21    2.32    9   7   8   520 440 1
          22    2.79    8   8   7   610 530 1
          23    3.21    7   9   8   505 435 1
          24    3.08    9   10  8   559 607 1
          25    3.75    10  9   9   760 620 1
          26    3.16    10  9   8   640 490 1
          27    2.73    9   8   7   520 360 1
          28    3.06    8   10  10  580 460 1
          29    1.07    7   8   6   700 520 1
          30    3.35    10  10  10  620 570 1
          31    1.82    6   8   6   490 550 1
          32    3.12    10  10  7   640 520 1
          33    2.25    9   7   4   550 290 1
          34    2.93    10  10  10  600 520 1
          35    3.16    9   7   7   400 390 1
          36    2.83    10  9   9   710 530 1
          37    3.10    9   10  9   750 670 1
          38    3.07    7   4   7   660 480 1
          39    2.87    9   9   9   620 480 1
          40    3.61    10  10  9   630 440 1
          41    2.17    10  7   7   650 450 1
          42    1.95    7   8   9   550 570 1
          43    3.35    10  10  10  730 650 1
          44    3.58    10  7   8   710 400 1
          45    2.75    10  7   5   770 720 1
          46    3.26    10  10  9   610 560 1
          47    3.41    9   4   7   600 360 1
          48    3.67    10  10  10  640 570 1
          49    3.81    10  10  7   750 540 1
          50    3.30    10  10  9   650 480 1
          51    2.30    9   10  10  590 420 1
          52    3.62    10  10  8   660 630 1
          53    3.20    9   5   7   570 570 1
          54    2.55    7   8   8   570 480 1
          55    2.82    10  9   9   660 550 1
          56    3.25    9   7   8   690 550 1
          57    2.21    7   7   8   670 500 1
          58    2.50    10  9   9   660 460 1
          59    3.03    8   8   7   600 630 1
          60    1.92    9   10  8   447 320 1
          61    4.00    7   6   6   600 410 1
          62    1.81    9   9   9   620 580 1
          63    2.70    6   8   6   580 470 1
          64    2.96    9   7   8   630 630 1
          65    2.76    10  10  10  600 560 1
          66    2.71    8   7   9   700 440 1
          67    3.40    9   10  9   550 560 1
          68    2.65    8   10  8   680 450 1
          69    2.48    8   8   7   630 500 1
          70    3.86    10  10  10  750 760 1
          71    2.62    9   8   7   491 391 1
          72    3.72    7   8   7   550 500 1
          73    3.50    8   7   8   630 500 1
          74    2.83    6   7   7   690 440 1
          75    3.06    8   6   5   540 400 1
          76    4.00    9   10  10  640 480 1
          77    3.70    8   10  8   520 410 1
          78    2.81    9   7   4   559 488 1
          79    1.93    8   6   8   590 510 1
          80    3.70    10  10  10  580 580 1
          81    2.96    9   7   6   670 440 1
          82    2.64    9   9   8   620 590 1
          83    3.09    10  10  8   540 470 1
          84    3.00    4   3   4   620 560 1
          85    2.97    10  10  10  770 540 1
          86    2.81    10  10  10  620 570 1
          87    3.32    10  9   10  660 560 1
          88    3.40    7   8   4   710 500 1
          89    1.84    9   6   6   610 390 1
          90    0.40    6   6   7   560 690 1
          91    2.88    9   7   6   690 460 1
          92    2.77    6   5   9   590 440 1
          93    2.26    5   7   7   530 440 1
          94    2.03    6   7   9   540 610 1
          95    2.43    7   10  10  530 560 1
          96    2.63    10  10  6   640 500 1
          97    1.66    8   4   3   590 470 1
          98    3.41    9   9   9   520 490 1
          99    2.12    7   7   8   559 545 1
         100    3.33    7   6   7   500 460 1
         101    1.69    8   7   7   490 390 1
         102    2.46    6   7   7   490 370 1
         103    1.59    8   9   7   670 480 1
         104    1.14    10  10  7   720 610 1
         105    0.65    9   7   7   640 520 1
         106    2.12    7   6   7   520 380 1
         107    2.82    4   5   7   400 470 1
         108    2.34    8   9   7   480 410 1
         109    2.11    6   9   9   480 390 1
         110    1.34    6   7   8   530 470 1
         111    2.53    8   9   8   550 500 1
         112    2.75    10  10  10  720 500 1
         113    3.14    9   8   9   640 630 1
         114    2.25    10  10  10  690 580 1
         115    1.00    8   9   10  640 600 1
         116    2.79    9   6   7   690 400 1
         117    2.39    6   5   6   470 330 1
         118    2.15    6   6   6   480 460 1
         119    0.75    7   6   6   540 590 1
         120    3.06    5   9   9   510 380 1
         121    2.50    9   9   9   560 500 1
         122    2.78    9   9   10  600 510 1
         123    2.44    8   8   8   690 490 1
         124    1.11    7   7   7   590 480 1
         125    3.12    10  10  10  580 340 1
         126    2.17    8   7   8   650 500 1
         127    0.12    4   6   6   630 490 1
         128    2.00    6   5   6   530 320 1
         129    3.22    9   7   9   650 490 1
         130    1.88    10  6   6   620 430 1
         131    2.04    8   7   7   690 440 1
         132    2.58    10  9   9   720 740 1
         133    2.16    6   6   6   590 440 1
         134    2.50    7   10  10  630 500 1
         135    1.85    10  8   7   700 480 1
         136    1.46    7   7   8   630 540 1
         137    2.95    9   9   8   620 400 1
         138    0.80    8   10  9   470 410 1
         139    0.91    6   5   7   586 697 1
         140    2.67    9   9   10  586 670 1
         141    2.51    9   8   7   700 500 1
         142    1.79    7   7   5   550 570 1
         143    2.42    6   6   8   505 518 1
         144    0.58    5   7   7   515 285 1
         145    3.00    10  10  9   774 688 1
         146    2.76    10  10  10  570 570 0
         147    3.35    9   9   9   580 540 0
         148    3.80    10  9   8   560 530 0
         149    2.38    9   9   10  650 570 0
         150    2.58    10  10  9   440 430 0
         151    3.18    10  10  10  570 750 0
         152    2.87    8   8   7   476 576 0
         153    3.16    8   9   8   680 700 0
         154    3.07    9   8   9   490 480 0
         155    3.68    10  8   9   590 490 0
         156    3.34    10  9   10  590 580 0
         157    1.93    10  8   8   650 490 0
         158    2.43    9   5   9   480 520 0
         159    3.28    10  10  10  670 490 0
         160    3.66    10  10  10  710 600 0
         161    2.29    7   6   8   570 570 0
         162    2.19    6   5   6   540 460 0
         163    3.06    10  10  10  620 510 0
         164    3.41    8   6   8   630 470 0
         165    3.14    9   9   10  630 700 0
         166    2.85    10  8   8   610 460 0
         167    3.47    10  10  9   720 680 0
         168    3.44    10  10  9   640 590 0
         169    3.90    10  10  10  650 500 0
         170    3.65    9   9   9   640 430 0
         171    1.32    9   8   9   740 460 0
         172    3.23    10  10  10  600 660 0
         173    2.86    10  9   10  650 430 0
         174    2.51    8   9   10  510 440 0
         175    2.86    8   9   8   550 510 0
         176    3.34    10  9   9   570 530 0
         177    3.33    9   7   9   630 560 0
         178    3.69    10  10  8   710 470 0
         179    1.80    7   7   7   620 470 0
         180    2.57    9   10  10  417 518 0
         181    2.28    8   10  10  600 600 0
         182    1.60    4   7   7   460 460 0
         183    2.00    2   4   6   300 290 0
         184    1.69    7   6   7   560 480 0
         185    3.06    9   10  9   590 420 0
         186    2.75    8   9   8   559 435 0
         187    2.62    9   10  8   550 440 0
         188    0.39    7   10  9   550 660 0
         189    2.44    10  9   9   650 350 0
         190    3.46    9   9   8   610 520 0
         191    2.37    8   7   9   530 480 0
         192    1.25    7   8   6   480 360 0
         193    2.80    10  9   9   550 450 0
         194    2.14    5   4   8   560 420 0
         195    2.45    7   7   8   430 330 0
         196    2.71    9   7   10  490 400 0
         197    2.59    10  10  10  590 470 0
         198    2.93    9   9   10  690 510 0
         199    2.53    7   6   9   570 480 0
         200    1.95    6   6   9   550 600 0
         201    3.39    9   9   10  510 570 0
         202    2.69    8   6   9   470 420 0
         203    1.94    8   8   8   470 330 0
         204    3.00    10  8   9   510 360 0
         205    2.09    9   7   8   450 460 0
         206    1.85    10  8   10  530 550 0
         207    3.34    10  9   10  490 410 0
         208    2.25    6   9   10  530 510 0
         209    4.00    10  10  10  580 490 0
         210    2.72    6   5   7   580 490 0
         211    2.61    9   7   8   620 420 0
         212    2.32    6   6   7   430 460 0
         213    3.39    10  10  10  500 390 0
         214    3.64    8   6   8   590 580 0
         215    1.80    8   7   9   620 600 0
         216    1.52    9   9   10  520 570 0
         217    3.40    6   9   9   480 480 0
         218    2.86    9   4   8   640 470 0
         219    3.32    10  9   10  640 560 0
         220    2.07    9   7   6   600 440 0
         221    0.85    7   7   9   510 480 0
         222    1.86    7   9   7   356 350 0
         223    2.59    5   4   7   630 470 0
         224    2.28    9   8   9   559 488 0
   ", "Input", CharacterEncoding -> "MacintoshRoman"]}, 
 WindowSize -> {740, 597}, 
 WindowMargins -> {{270, Automatic}, {Automatic, 50}}, 
 FrontEndVersion -> 
  "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (January 25, 2013)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

And I'm not sure what to do; I'm pretty new to Mathematica. I've made numerous attempts to remove the cases at the end using the `DeleteCases` function,

```
DeleteCases[data,{_String},{-2}];
```

As well as, using the `Flatten` function. My thought is that the reason they can't be deleted in this way is because they're a part of a larger cell than what I've specified, but I'm not sure how to correct this. I can't begin data analysis with these elements at the end of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data2= StringSplit /@ StringSplit[Cases[data, Cell[t_, "Input", ___] :> t, Infinity], "\n"]
```

gives

[image]

You can convert the strings to numbers using

```
ToExpression/@data2
```

Comment: ah this takes care of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Lame-Ov2.0, may pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.